# Как парсить в данной ситуации? Jsoup

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

Делаю парсинг с помощью Jsoup. Есть блоки сайта, из которых нужн вытащить данные. Неторые из блоком имеют метку **class = "date"**, а некоторые **class = "date dateFree"** 
В строке Elements dayElements = document.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "date"); выбираются блоки только первого варианта. Как сделать так, чтобы просматривались блоки с обоими вариантами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать `document.getElementsByClass('date')` или селектор `document.select('.date')`.